# How do I know if a user came to my app via Nearby Notifications?

Tags: android, ibeacon, google-nearby

I want to get the number of clicks my App Intent gets when user comes in proximity of Nearby Beacons.

Comment: I believe this can be tracked by adding query string parameters into the path component of the intent URL. Quoting from Google Nearby Notifications FAQs: _Nearby Notifications links are standard Android deep links, but if you want to supply additional tags, for example, for metrics or analytics, you can add query string parameters into the path component of the intent URL._

Comment: Thank you so much Avinash, but can you give me the format in which i have to add the query string in path component.